# Singled ended or Differential - Engine Control Unit

Tags: differential, single-ended

I know this topic has been beaten to death but I still have not got a clear understanding. Pardon me for my bad explanation as I am an automotive engineer by trade.

I am simulating an engine knock event using a signal generator, which is basically a voltage signal in the range -5v to +5v and feeding it to an engine control unit (black box) to validate few functions. But the hardware documentation of the engine control unit mentions that it requires a knock signal from a differential knock sensor(Input + & Input - and no ground wire). The signal generator is a single ended signal and the pinouts of the signal generator are Input + and GND. My question is would the signal from the signal generator be compatible with the engine control unit?.

Thank you in advance.
Vish

Comment: Your words: **the hardware documentation of the engine control unit mentions that it requires a knock signal from a differential knock sensor(Input + & Input - and no ground wire).**

Comment: probably not compatible... does the ECU source current on the + and - lines (like phantom power) or are they just isolated? what does the sensor look like electrically? a switch? a capacitor? an inductor? a sidac?

Comment: Hi Jason and Andy. Thank you for your replies! @Jason: I am not sure if I understand your question about ECU source current. And the sensor is basically a piezo electric type sensor.

Comment: 'Try' capacitive coupling both leads of the generator. If you can "float the generator even better.